# Running a Spring EnvironmentPostProcessor after processing PropertySource annotations of a profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I currently fail to implement an (kind of a) `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, which should replace some properties based the values of another set of properties.

This works fine, if I add the properties I need to one of the usual `application*.yaml` files. But the properties I need are provided by a profile, which is defined as follows

```java
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:development.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:development-logging.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "file:./local-development-configuration.properties")
@Profile("development")
@Configuration
public class DevelopmentConfiguration {
}
```

So I need an `EnviromentPostProcessor`, which hooks in after this profile has been activated.

Does anyone know how to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved via :

```
public class EnvPostProcessImpl implements EnvironmentPostProcessor{
..
 
 @Autowired 
 DevelopmentConfiguration config;

 @Override
 public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
  SpringApplication application){
  if (Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles()).contains("development")) {

   // populate your properties with help of `config` reference we autowired above.
   }   
}
```

So basically, you can just check if active profile is `development` & if it so, just use reference of config & populate properties.